# Review page doesn't have mobile layout

Tags: feature-request, review, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review option on mobile phone not available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available)

While surfing SO with my iPod touch, I ended up on the review page and got the standard layout instead of the mobile version. I think it would be great to have a mobile version of this page as well, since reviewing and flagging doesn't require using the iPod's rather horrible virtual keyboard as much as answering and commenting.

Comment: Yep on my android phone now and couldn't even find the review button! :(

Comment: And as a kicker: the page has a "mobile" link down at the bottom which just reloads the desktop view.  Sadistic, much?