# Layer with infotext on review page on mobile devices

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web, review

When editing posts from the reviewing queue a layer containing a short explanation and the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> and <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> buttons is being displayed. This layer always stays visible on top of the displayed area:

[image: Reviewing on a PC]

While this is certainly useful on any normal PC this can be quite annoying when reviewing and editing posts on a mobile device:

[image: Reviewing on an iPhone]

It would be great if there would be the possibility to "unpin" this layer so that it's not in the way when editing posts.

There's [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109035/review-page-doesnt-have-mobile-layout) here on meta that handles a related issue, but my question is not about a mobile layout for the entire reviewing section, but rather for a small improvement to the existing layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stickiness of the review "action bar" has been disabled on mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick action, but even after clearing the browser cache the action bar is still sticky and hovering above the editing area on iOS.

Comment: I re-checked that behaviour: When editing a post from the review section, the action bar is still floating on iOS/Safari. Once in Edit mode (that is to say, the focus is in the textarea and the keyboard is being displayed) the action bar is no longer changing its position but remains at its last position, which is most likely on top of the textarea...

Comment: Re-checked again now. Works fine.