# Review option on mobile phone not available?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, review, mobile-web

The other day I was looking at Stack Overflow on my Android phone. All is made very nice and all, but I could not find the **Review** button/link. Is it being implemented, did I miss it, or it is not available?

Comment: I don't have an android but did you try searching the marketplace?

Comment: Given the often mangled and hard to read appearance of the mobile site, I don't think that's the best review platform to begin with. :(

Comment: I looked around Google Play a.k.a. marketplace, but didn't find any official app's. Found one, but said in description that it only wraps the URL mobile link in the application.

Comment: @Marko there are official apps now, but neither contain any review, so it's not relevant. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have heard that the support for review is comming in *6-8 weeks* ;)

Comment: @Marko LOL... yeah, the world will end 6-8 times before review will be added to mobile theme, or the official app(s). :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard MSE comments are a wonderful thing. Where has this been?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We currently do not have a mobile version of /review.  You can visit /review on a mobile device however it will not be optimized for a mobile device. We have a longer term goal of making a mobile version.

Comment: I can't wait to have this up!

Comment: hey it's been much more than six to eight weeks :P

Comment: So you have a mobile review site in planning, but you aren't going to add flagging history to the mobile site?

Comment: @Geoff year and four months later, any update on this?

Comment: Please remind me to recheck this question in six to eight years.

Comment: This is your friendly annual request for status.

Comment: @Matt pointless, they are ignoring comments.

Comment: I assume your longer term goal was never accomplished looking at this topic being many years back. It's very unfortunate the mobile app does not have the review features.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You mean all the upvotes he would have gotten if the answer had been status-confirmed?

Comment: @Fiksdal no, I don't expect or ask the developers to fix all the bugs, but I do expect them to reply to update requests, even "Sorry, this is not really planned yet" just so we know they hear us.

Comment: Ah, yes, agreed. New [tag:feature-request]: @ShadowWizard should be able to cast 100 downvotes on a single answer on each of his birthdays. (Only for Shadow Wizard, feature doesn't apply to anyone else.)

Comment: @Fiksdal actually 50 downvotes are enough, but that would be cool! ;-) (or, negative bounty... ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard LOL at negative bounty. I'm assuming you also get to steal the rep from the other user? Haha.

Comment: Well finally I can downvote this. @Fiksdal

Comment: @Jan exactly three years after your comment, and guess what? We are being ignored! Hooray.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not surprised. Please remind me again in another three to five years.

Comment: I will bring this back to the attention of the team working on the Q&A mobile experience.  I agree that it has been lacking attention.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Thanks, as for now, in 2017, almost 40% of the site usage are from mobile device, if the charts are good. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9uWe.png)

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: @apaul in 6-8 years, of course.

Comment: This is your friendly annual request for status.

Comment: Review queues are currently under redesign: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview?cb=1 I'd point you over there as I'm not in the loop on these at the moment.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, but then I discovered the **full site** link in the bottom right hand corner of the site, and got full-page loveliness with all the usual stuff.

Answer (score 6):

IMO,  this is a pretty good idea,  and I don't see why it would be a low priority. Also, I'm sure it could also be implemented in the mobile **apps**. And hopefully it might take less than 6 to 8 years to implement. Of course, it would require a team of skilled software developers, but the word on the street these days is that this is something SE is in possession of.

Some sites ([like Ask Ubuntu,  for example](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16116/451919)) have lots of work pending in the review queue, due to a continuous influx of new users (among other things).

If the review queue was more inviting on mobile devices, users may feel inclined to do it as a way to pass the time while commuting to work, waiting for something, etc.

You know how some people sit on the bus browsing their Facebook feeds,  etc? Often, it's because they are bored, and want something to stimulate their minds. Out of all the millions of SE users,  I'm sure many do this. In this way, much of this energy can be turned into something useful.

Encouraging people to help out more, in this way, would probably benefit sites like that (and,  of course, the whole network) by bringing more eyes and hands to the review queue. This will certainly improve the overall quality and tidiness of the whole network.  Close-worthy questions will be closed faster, improved ones will be reopened faster, spam will be deleted sooner,  poorly written posts will be improved sooner (or at all), etc, etc.

I sometimes do this on my phone using the desktop version of the site.  But a mobile optimized interface would certainly be more inviting, appealing and encouraging to users.

Comment: AFAIK (and I may be wrong), /review isn't accessible through the API which the apps use so it's not an easy thing to implement. Review on the mobile *site* shouldn't be that hard to implement though.

Comment: @Cai Thanks for informing me of that,  I changed the wording accordingly.