# It seems I cannot approve edits on iPad with iOS 6 on full site

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ipad

I am on the **full site** on my iPad and clicking approve does nothing.

This is NOT a duplicate of [Review option on mobile phone not available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available)

Am I the only one with that problem?

Comment: I'm reopening the question since it doesn't look like a duplicate, but please don't edit the "Possible duplicate" section out of the question body again. It just makes it more difficult for folks with the power to reopen your question to check if the suggested duplicate is wrong.

Comment: I've been reproducing this for a week or so now on my iPad (also full site).  Seemed to have coincided with the release of iOS 6.0.1, though I can't say for sure. This report leaves many details out - if the root cause isn't clear, I'll come by in a little bit with more repro details.

Comment: Thanks @AnnaLear - I had not seen the auto insert before, so when I edited, I of course wanted it gone.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. In my case it is not related to iOS 6.0.1 - it happened on 6.0 as well. I've tried clearing all site data (cookies, etc.) and still am unable to review. Any action (approve, etc.) results in the same item being loaded. No result at all to the action.