# Unable to dismiss the reviews badge progress dialog On iOS safari

Tags: bug, review, badge-progress, ios

When reviewing posts in the [reviews section](https://stackoverflow.com/review), there is no way to dismiss the "badge progress" popup on an iOS device.  This can be a pain as the popup appears over the top of the review action buttons (close, edit, skip, etc.).

Comment: Considering the review panel is not part of the mobile site, it's not really *meant* to be used on mobile devices, so why would there be a way to do that on a mobile device? You're basically asking them to build a mobile version of the review panel...

Comment: @animuson And what if I've got an iPad, then (BTW, this still appears on an iPad).  Are you saying that it would be too much work to add a little black x to the popup window so I can get to the very buttons I'm in the editing queue for without a reload?

Comment: @CodaFi: You [wait for the promised mobile version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148633). The badge progress popup uses the same scripting that the tag popups and user card popups utilize - so yes, adding a "little black x" to the popup is a lot of effort to optimize the page for a device it wasn't meant for.