# Features missing in Mobile view

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, mobile-web

When viewing stack exchange sites on my iPhone, I've noticed that a few things are missing. In particular, the link for the review page and the search feature appear to be missing. I've also noticed that the favourite and ignore tags list are also missing. Is there any plan to expand the mobile experience so that it will include more of the features found in the wider browser version?

I'm on my phone as I ask this, I was not able to see if a similar question had been asked previously because the search feature is not there or I can't find it.

Comment: The search box is in the top right corner of the drop-down when you hit the down arrow in the top right corner. [Review for Mobile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148633) is on their list, but not yet supported. You can always go to /review manually to use the full site version.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I managed to miss that the search feature was in that place, even though I've opened it several times already.

Comment: Sometimes I wish SO had an official mobile app, making things like /review and /tools easier to use.

Comment: On mobile, there is a link back to "full site" at the bottom.