# Android app doesn't show suggested edit notifications in the inbox

Tags: bug, android-app

I have recently been informed about suggested edit via web:

> [image: web]

But I can't see this notification inside android-app inbox:

> [image: app]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1626721325f7f)

Comment: Does http://stackexchange.com/topbar/inbox show the notification?

Comment: @Cai yes. `edit suggested 1 hour ago
What does mean "up arrow" in the top posts section of the user profile?`

Comment: I think that is by-design since you can't review it from there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I can't use chat inside app too, but I can see chat message. And open chat in browser after tapping. Suggested edit notification could be used in a same manner.

Comment: That is a valid point. I guess the reason there can be: there is a mobile chat interface, but not a mobile review interface.

Comment: @PatrickHofman A reasonable explanation. Need to make suggested edit page is mobile compatible!

Comment: There is a FR for that already.

Answer (score 2):

The mobile app only shows actions that can be handled in the mobile app or the mobile web site.

There is a mobile-friendly site for chat, but [there is not a mobile site for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148616/245360), hence it isn't shown in the notifications. (Just like SO Documentation notifications, which are hidden too.) There is an exception though: SO Jobs notifications are shown in the app, I guess for obvious reasons.